# I want to group cat_id by partition window function

Tags: mysql

```
select row_number() over(partition by cat_id order by order_time desc) as row_num, order_id,location from order_table;
```

Whats wrong in this Query Window function is not running Its showing Error running query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by. Please can anyone help me here Breaking my head

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing seems wrong with your sql code. I tested with random data below using the version '@8.0.28'. Please check your version is fully supporting these capabilities. I

```
USE TEST;
CREATE TABLE order_table (order_id INT, cat_id INT, order_time DATETIME, location VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO order_table VALUES
(323412, 102, '2020-10-12 13:50:55', 'Seattle'),
(323413, 103, '2020-12-15 10:26:09', 'Kentucky'),
(323414, 104, '2020-05-03 23:34:12', 'Alabama'),
(323415, 103, '2020-06-07 16:40:23', 'Seattle'),
(323416, 104, '2020-11-19 12:20:54', 'Alabama'),
(323417, 102, '2020-12-20 11:40:15', 'Arizona'),
(323418, 103, '2020-04-26 14:33:37', 'Seattle'),
(323419, 104, '2020-02-12 10:21:23', 'Alabama'),
(323420, 102, '2020-09-23 09:31:21', 'California');

select row_number() over(partition by cat_id order by order_time desc) as row_num, order_id,location from order_table;

Result_set:
[Result_sets][1]
```